# Input text alignment is behaving differently in different browser

Tags: html, css

I am using box for token code purpose but input text alignment is coming different in different browser.
**In Chrome:**

[image]

**In Internet Explorer:**

[image]

My code for input text and for box is below:

```html
<style>
input.box {
 height: 9px;
 padding: 3px 3px 8px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 width: 145px;
 padding-top: 4px;
}
</style>


<input path="token" id="token" tabindex="2" maxlength="35" class="box"
        placeholder="token"  />
```

we can see the bottom space is more in ***Chrome*** compare to ***Internet Explorer*** in the box.

Please let me know, how to fix this?

Comment: try to <!--[if IE]>
input.box {
 
 padding-top: 4px; /* adjust value */
}
<![endif]-->

Comment: @core114 IE does not support padding, and if I remember correctly the if clause does not work since IE10

Comment: @MatthiasS. sir, good point, Because the different browser have different font styling even though you set the font-styling. Similarly ie have different front size. so you can write the code for IE.

Here the link to help how to specific css in ie only. https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: down voter please comment why they have down voted it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the CSS like this answer:

```css
input.box {
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 145px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<input path="token" id="token" tabindex="2" maxlength="35" class="box" placeholder="token" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `<input>` Elements, or form elements in general, depending on the browser itself, it is up to the browser (and the operating system), how they look. So for example `padding` is supported by Chrome and Firefox on Windows, but the IE does not support it.

As a workaround, you could add a `line-height`, look at the example below:

```css
input.box {
    height: 9px;
    padding: 3px 3px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 145px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    line-height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<input path="token" id="token" tabindex="2" maxlength="35" class="box"
        placeholder="token"  />
```

Comment: what will be best suggestion for that??

Comment: try to avoid paddigns

Comment: I added a workaround for IE, please look at the snippet

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you can use the `line-height` CSS property to do this. Simply set it to be the same as the `height` of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) instead of `padding` for the IE.

Comment: 30 seconds faster than the edit of my answer. Good job, take my upvote ;)

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: propably a strategic downvote. Not mine, I even gave you an upvote

Comment: Meaning there's nothing wrong with my answer and someone is just being an arse, right? As I am using this solution on production for over a year now and I'd be very sad if it was wrong.

Comment: A unpopular practise by some people who [downvote the answers of other people to make their own show up higher](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316128/strategic-downvotes-negatively-affect-the-community). But I don't want to start a witchhunt, could also be some "I downvoted because of reasons" guy ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156355/discussion-between-matthias-s-and-wscourge).